# JQuery clearInterval() is adding a delay

Tags: jquery, css, performance, setinterval, clearinterval

I am making a photo slider for my website and didn't get any answers on my previous question so I managed to figure it out myself.

Everything is running fine but I have a navigation bar for my slider, and when you click on a title in the bar, the photo relevant to that title shows up. I'm using clearInterval() to achieve this, but it is causing a delay when you click. So instead of clicking on the title and the picture immediately switches, a few seconds go by and then finally the image shows up. I'd like to avoid this delay. Any ideas? Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body onload="slider();">
<div id="slider">
 <div class="slider">
  <a href="#"><img id="1" src="2013Sealbeach.jpg" border="0" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img id="2" src="sns-homeintro-WEB.jpg" border="0" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img id="3" src="2013facebookad.jpg" border="0" /></a>
 </div> <!-- /.slider -->

  <div class="sliderBar">
          <div id="one" class="sliderBarDiv"><p id="sliderBarNavs">Seal Beach Bodyboarding</p></div>
          <div id="two" class="sliderBarDiv"><p id="sliderBarNavs">The Team</p></div>
          <div id="three" class="sliderBarDiv"><p id="sliderBarNavs">Second Nature Skimboarding</p></div>
  </div> <!-- /.sliderBar -->
</div> <!-- /#slider -->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#sliderBarNavs /* the text for the slider bar */
{
    margin:auto;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#999;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}
#sliderBarNavs:hover
{
    color:#9CF;
}
#slider
{
    width:750px;
    height:536px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slider
{
    width:750px;
    height:486px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(Loading.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
.slider img
{
    width:750px;
    height:486px;
    display:none;
}
.sliderBar
{
    width:750px;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
.sliderBarDiv
{
    width:140px;
    height:40px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-right:1px solid #CCC;
    border-left:1px solid #CCC;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.sliderBarDiv:hover
{
    background-color:#f4f4f4;
}
```

JQuery:

```
function slider() {
$(".slider #1").fadeIn(500);
$(".slider #1").delay(5000).fadeOut(500);

var sc=$(".slider img").size();
var count=2;
var pause;

pause = setInterval(function() {
                     $(".slider #"+count).fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
                     if(count==sc){
                         count = 1
                     }else{
                         count = count + 1;
                     }
                     }, 6000);

$("#one, #two, #three").click(function(){
                       clearInterval(pause);
                         });
}

$(document).ready(function(){ // to navigate through the images once the setInterval has been cleared:

$("#one").click(function(){
            $(".slider #1").fadeIn(500);
                         });
$("#two").click(function(){
            $(".slider #1").fadeOut(250);
            $(".slider #2").fadeIn(250);
                         });
$("#three").click(function(){
            $(".slider #1").fadeOut(250);
            $(".slider #3").fadeIn(250);
                         });
$("#three").click(function(){
            $(".slider #2").fadeOut(250);
            $(".slider #3").fadeIn(250);
                         });
});
```

The pictures I used are on local file so anyone who helps me with this is going to need to use pictures from online, other than that anyone who can help me would be great, this is really frustrating and I can't find answers anywhere else. Also, I know that there is probably an easier way to code most of the JQuery to make it more compressed, but I'm pretty new to js and JQuery so that's the best I could do. Thanks!

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/C398M/

Comment: @Enve that doesn't fix what I'm trying to solve. It's not a problem with the delay after the clearInterval(pause) has been executed but rather a delay in clearing the interval. If that makes sense

Comment: When we put the code into jsFiddle the clearInterval doesn't work, there's nothing to fire it besides onLoad. Do you have an example we can use?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a slider for me either http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/t2WZK/

Comment: @Zeaklous yea for some reason its running weird in jsfiddle. I'm using DreamWeaver and testing it in Safari and Firefox and clearInterval works fine, except for the delay problem I'm having.

Comment: @Zeaklous well the reason why there's no slider is because the pictures are on my local file. you'd need to use pictures that are online to test it, or if you use a text editor application then use your own local files

Comment: Here I have added the images and your code http://jsfiddle.net/enve/C398M/1/

Comment: @Enve hmm that's really weird...I'm thinking maybe jsfiddle doesn't have support for set and clearInterval? Because the slider itself is running fine on Safari and Firefox

Comment: Yes I tested it on my computer and it works as you said. After clicking one title it is delaying 5 seconds and then switching to another one. I am working on a solution.

Comment: @Enve alright cool. I'll wait to hear from you. Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is in delay(5000)` and not in `clearInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace in jQuery this code

```
$(".slider #1").delay(5000).fadeOut(500);
```

with this

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".slider #1").fadeOut(500);
},5000)
```

And  it will work (tested).

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/C398M/2/